# QueryString converting %E1 to %ufffd

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, query-string, urlencode

I have a URL like the following

```
http://mysite.com/default.aspx?q=%E1
```

Where `%E1` is supposed to be `á`. When I call `Request.QueryString` from my C# page I receive

```
http://mysite.com/default.aspx?q=%ufffd
```

It does this for any accented character. `%E1, %E3, %E9, %ED` etc. all get passed as `%ufffd`. Normal encoded values (`%2D`, `%2E`, `%27`) all get passed correctly.

The config file already has the `responseEncoding`/`requestEncoding` in the globalization section set to UTF-8.

How could I read the correct values?

Please note that I'm not the one generating the query string and I have no control over it.

Comment: Maybe you just think that the URL looks like this %E1 because it is shown so in your browser's address bar but actually alway is like the %ufffd?

Comment: @UweKeim, I can type the URL in directly with the same result. It does exist on the query string, it just seems to get mangled somewhere.

Comment: Does the iis request tracing reveal something helpful? E.g. Whether a rewrite occurs? Or how about using Microsoft Network Monitor on your client?

Comment: @UweKeim, The trace shows `�` as the value of the parameter. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it's true that `á` is encoded as [U+00E1](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e1/index.htm), the UTF-8 encoding (which is relevant for URL parameters) is `0xC3 0xA1`.

You can verify by called a Wikipedia entry on an accented letter, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81

[U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) is the Unicode Replacement Character which indicates the a given character value cannot be correctly encoded in Unicode.

Update:

Your question has two points.

First: How do I encode a Unicode string as parameter. Use

```
"?q=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value)
```

Second: How do I retrieve a Unicode value? Use:

```
Request["q"]
```

If you receive the `%E1` from some other source you do not control, maybe the RawUrl can help you. (I have not tried)

Comment: Is there any way to get it encoded properly in Unicode then? Basically I have to validate a hash code against the query string to validate that it is legitimate. Which means I need the *exact* string that was passed to me. I can do a string substitution, but I still need to get the proper value first.

Comment: `RawUrl` seems to give me the proper value. I suppose I can split the QueryString out myself and do the parsing. Thanks!