# Decode this kind of path url?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string, url

I would like to know if .Net Framework Class Library provides a method or a way to efficientlly decode this kind of path url:

```
file:///C:/Users/Administrador/Downloads/V%EDdeos
```

The problem is the escaped characters where in this example `%ED` is really an `í`

I've tried the decoder methods of `System.Web.HttpUtility` Class but didn't solved the problem.

Comment: have you tried `System.Uri`?

Comment: @Daniel A. White now I've tried it, it does not solve the character format problem

Comment: MAYBE have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14327085/querystring-converting-e1-to-ufffd and then also at `RawURL` / URLEncoding? - Just thinking, but never tried it.... Hence leaving it as a comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpUtility.UrlDecode` has an overload that takes an `Encoding` parameter.

You'd just have to specify Latin1 encoding (ISO-8859-1):

```
string input = "file:///C:/Users/Administrador/Downloads/V%EDdeos";
string decoded = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(input, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Comment: Thanks I really didn't noticed it, just one thing to note: its sufficient to pass `Encoding.Default` as parameter because it contains the default ANSI code page then no need to specify the Latin ISO. thanks again

Comment: @ElektroStudios, yw, be careful with `Encoding.Default` though, the current system code page could vary on different systems.